# Regex to extract a number and its unit of measure that are separated by a string from a word of interest

Tags: r, regex, string, text-mining

I'm learning R and I'm trying to use regex to extract specific text. I would like to capture a number and the unit of measure from a recipe for a specific ingredient.

For example for the following text:

```
text <-  c("0.5 Tb of butter","3 grams (0.75 sticks) of chilled butter","2 tbs softened butter", "0.3 Tb of milk")
```

I would like to extract the numbers and units relating only to butter, i.e:

```
0.5 Tb
3 grams
2 tbs
```

I think this would be best done using regex, but I'm quite new to this so I'm struggling somewhat.

Using str_match I can get the number in front of specific unit like this:

```
str_match(text, "\\s*(\\d+)\\s*Tb")
     [,1]   [,2]
[1,] "5 Tb" "5" 
[2,] NA     NA  
[3,] NA     NA  
[4,] "3 Tb" "3"
```

But how could I get only the values that relate to butter and for a range of units. Is it possible to make a list of possible units (i.e. grams, tbs, Tb etc.) and ask to match any of them (so that in this example grams would match but not sticks)?

Or perhaps this would be done better with some loop? I could put each sentence into a dataframe, loop through each row asking if there is 'butter' in the row search for a number in it and extract the the number and the word that follows, which should be the unit of measure.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try [`str_match(text, "(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\s*(tbs?|gr(?:ams?)?|lb)(?=.*\\bbutter\\b)")`](https://regex101.com/r/Wo1Sh1/1) if you need the numbers and measurement units in separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution would be to `grep` out the butter lines and then use `read.table` to parse them given that the matched items are always the first two fields.  No packages are used and the only regular expression used is the simple expression `butter`.

```
butter <- grep("butter", text, value = TRUE)
read.table(text = butter, fill = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)[1:2]
```

giving:

```
   V1    V2
1 0.5    Tb
2 3.0 grams
3 2.0   tbs
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to detect the 'butter' in the strings and then use `str_extract`

```
str_extract(grep("butter", text, value = TRUE), "[0-9.]+\\s+\\w+")
#[1] "0.5 Tb"  "3 grams" "2 tbs"
```

---

Or using `str_detect` with `str_extract`

```
library(tidyverse)
str_detect(text, "butter") %>% 
    extract(text, .) %>%
    str_extract("[0-9.]+\\s+\\w+")
#[1] "0.5 Tb"  "3 grams" "2 tbs"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at something like this `([\d.]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+).*butter`

Answer (score 0):

```
sub("^(\\S+\\s+\\S+).*", "\\1", text[grepl("butter", text)])
[1] "0.5 Tb"  "3 grams" "2 tbs"
```

`\\s+` to match any number of spaces and `\\S+` to match any number of non-spaces. `^` to start at the beginning.

`text[grepl("butter", text)]` returns only the text elements which contain the word butter. Perhaphs add the argument `ignore.case = TRUE` to `grepl()` for it to also match `Butter`...